# What was the story of Saraswati taking a princess to another universe to show her an alternate version of her father?

Tags: scripture, gods, goddess

I heard about this story before, but I can't remember where to find it.

Comment: It is not father, it is husband. Right?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it was a man important in her life?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story of Saraswati taking princess Lila to another universe to show the next birth of her (dead) husband is present in the scripture [Yoga Vasistha](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english).

The whole story is from [section 15](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118069.html) to [section 60](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118118.html).

The name of princess is Lila. Her name is Arundathi in her previous life. The name of Lila's husband is Padma and his name is Vasistha in his previous life.

The names of her husband are as follows

> Vaistha (previous life) -> Padma (current life) -> Viduratha (next
> life)

The names of wives of Padma are as follows

> Arundati (Vaistha's wife) -> Lila (Padma's wife) -> Lila (Viduratha's
> wife)

It is important to note that same Jiva is present in Vasistha, Padma and Viduratha. But Padma's wife Lila is different from Viduratha's wife Lila. Arundati and Lila has same Jiva, who is different from the Jiva of Viduratha's wife Lila.

Saraswati [sent](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118071.html) Padma's wife Lila to Viduratha's universe. Later, they [visit](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118073.html) Vaista and Arundati's universe. Afterwards, they both [visit](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/yoga-vasistha-english/d/doc118085.html) Viduratha's universe and finally arrives to the original Padma's universe. Viduratha's wife Lila also arrives to the Pama's universe and finally Padma continues to rule his kingdom along with two Lila's.

Comment: Can only deities travel to other universes, is that why Lila asked Saraswati for help?

Comment: @Orionixe Not only dieties, Yogi can also travel. Lila performs Yoga under the guidance of Saraswathi  for doing so. The story contains all the details related to that.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Stories about alternate universes is what makes HInduism so unique to me

Comment: @Orionixe Welcome.... There are plenty of questions about time, the universe, etc., you can read them....

Comment: @Orionixe, if you’re satisfied by the answer, you can accept it by pressing the tick button (✔️) below the voting arrows so that others on the site too can know that this is the correct answer. Also if you liked it and haven’t already done so, you might vote by pressing the up arrow. I’m telling you about accepting and upvoting because you’re new to the site. Welcome to HSE! btw.