# Instances of rebirth in difference universe in sanathan dharma

Tags: scripture, rebirth, universe

Sanathan dharma has many instances regarding rebirth.

For this question, I am classifying rebirth in to two categories according to the place of birth:

1. Rebirth in the same physical universe
2. Rebirth in a different physical universe

There are numerous examples in scriptures regarding rebirth of first category. This list includes the lives of Jada Bharata, Draupadi, Surpanaka etc., and the list is very large and most of the rebirths mentioned across scriptures belongs to the first category.

I know very less examples of rebirths belonging to the second category. This list include [lila and her family from Yoga Vasista](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44384/what-was-the-story-of-saraswati-taking-a-princess-to-another-universe-to-show-he). It is hard to get some other examples belonging to this category.

Are there any other instances of rebirths in difference universes from the scriptures of Sanathan Dharma?

Comment: Scripture does not address whether or not there is only one universe, or what the extent of that universe is. It only talks of kalpas, cycles, and even here it is not meant to based 'rock solid' deduction based logic of scientific rigor. Scripture is meant to address men of all ages, not whatever the current scientific or otherwise belief is. By assuming in your question different universes, you are making scientific speculation, as science has not definitely shown evidence as to the existence of other universes, the extent of this universe, etc.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda hahaha........